# Matrix Math With Sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, sparklyr

Looking to convert some R code to Sparklyr, functions such as lmtest::coeftest() and sandwich::sandwich(). Trying to get started with Sparklyr extensions but pretty new to the Spark API and having issues :(

Running Spark 2.1.1 and sparklyr 0.5.5-9002

Feel the first step would be to make a [DenseMatrix](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseMatrix) object using the linalg library:

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
sc <- spark_connect("local")

rows <- as.integer(2)
cols <- as.integer(2)
array <- c(1,2,3,4)

mat <- invoke_new(sc, "org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseMatrix", 
                  rows, cols, array)
```

This results in the error:

```
Error: java.lang.Exception: No matched constructor found for class org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseMatrix
```

Okay, so I got a java lang exception, I'm pretty sure the `rows` and `cols` args were fine in the constructor, but not sure sure about the last one, which is supposed to be a java `Array`. So I tried a few permutations of:

```
array <- invoke_new(sc, "java.util.Arrays", c(1,2,3,4))
```

but end up with a similar error message...

```
Error: java.lang.Exception: No matched constructor found for class java.util.Arrays
```

I feel like I'm missing something pretty basic. Anyone know what's up?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

R counterpart of the Java `Array` is `list`:

```
invoke_new(
  sc, "org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseMatrix",
  2L, 2L, list(1, 2, 3, 4))

## <jobj[17]>
##   class org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseMatrix
##   1.0  3.0  
## 2.0  4.0
```

or

```
invoke_static(
  sc, "org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Matrices", "dense",
  2L, 2L, list(1, 2, 3, 4))

## <jobj[19]>
##   class org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseMatrix
##   1.0  3.0  
## 2.0  4.0
```

Please note I am using `o.a.s.ml.linalg` instead of `o.a.s.mllib.linalg`. While `mllib` would work in isolation, as of Spark 2.x `o.a.s.ml` algorithms no longer accept local `o.a.s.mllib`.

At the same time R `vector` types (`numeric`, `integer`, `character`) are used as scalars.

**Note**:

Personally I believe this is not the way to go. Spark `linalg` packages are quite limited, and internally depend on the libraries, which won't be usable via `sparklyr`. Moreover `sparklyr` API is not suitable for complex logic.

In practice it makes more sense to implement Java or Scala extension, with a thin, R friendly wrapper.

Comment: regarding your note, do you know of any resources for making these extensions? Also any guides showing how to call custom extensions from R?

Comment: Sorry, I am not. There is of course [the official sparklyr guide](http://spark.rstudio.com/extensions.html), but I don't think it is that useful. Overall I think this more about API design. SparkR API is a nice example - with heavy logic implemented in Scala and thin, R-friendly adapters.

Comment: I very much appreciate your comments. Looks like we'll be doing some Scala programming. I know that we'll need the `rank` linear algebra method and `linalg` does not have it.

Comment: Yeah, if you need proper linear algebra libraries I would go directly to [Breeze](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/Quickstart). Design should be familiar enough if you worked with NumPy or Matlab, and it is already a dependency for Spark.

Comment: Update many years later. We ended up going the suggested route and made a Spark package written in Scala. Then we just made an R package that calls that Spark library.